# Splunk C# Client Issue #1: Custom Auth Token Header Gone Awry

Tags: c#, api, splunk

I wanted to go my own way before using the Splunk C# SDK. I made it past logging in, meaning I can retrieve a valid sessionKey in the response. My issue now is that creating search jobs is returning "Unauthorized."

According to the Splunk documentation this should work.
For simplicity:

```
    string newstring = string.Format("Splunk {0}", token);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", newstring);
```

But I keep getting this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <response>
    <messages>
    <msg type="ERROR">Unauthorized</msg>
    </messages>
    </response>
```

Even though a curl to the host of the same intent is successful.

```
    <response>
    <sid>1526955996.109</sid>
    </response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Token must have been malformed in the formatting.

```
    "Authorization",string.Format("Splunk {0}", token);
```